# Convert long type column to calendarinterval type in Spark SQL

Tags: sql, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Two queries:

How to convert long type column having numbers in seconds to calendarinterval type having in Python
    Spark SQL?

How to convert the below code to plain Spark SQL query:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import unix_timestamp
df2 = df.withColumn(
    "difference_duration",
    unix_timestamp("CAL_COMPLETION_TIME") - unix_timestamp("Prev_Time")
    )
```

Sample dataframe SS:
[image]

Basically am trying to achieve this below PGSQL query in Spark SQL:

```
case 
    when t1.prev_time <> t1.prev_time_calc and t1."CAL_COMPLETION_TIME" - t1.prev_time < interval '30 min' 
      then t1.next_time_calc - t1.prev_time_calc
    when (t1.next_time <> t1.next_time_calc and t1.next_time - t1."CAL_COMPLETION_TIME" < interval '30 min') or (t1.next_time - t1."CAL_COMPLETION_TIME" < interval '30 min')
      then t1.next_time_calc - t1."CAL_COMPLETION_TIME"
  else null
  end min_diff
```

But this part *t1."CAL_COMPLETION_TIME" - t1.prev_time < interval '30 min'* is throwing following error:

```
AnalysisException: "cannot resolve '(t1.`CAL_COMPLETION_TIME` - t1.`prev_time`)' due to data type mismatch: '(t1.`CAL_COMPLETION_TIME` - t1.`prev_time`)' requires (numeric or calendarinterval) type, not timestamp;
```

Comment: Could you please share a sample row of dataframe df.

Comment: Given more clarity on the problem statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't subtract timestamps, you need to **cast them to seconds.** Therefore, what you are looking for is to cast the timestamp columns to **long/bigint** as you are subtracting, `divide by 60` to get **minute value**, and then see if it is `less than 30`.

```
#example=df1
#both columns are of type Timestamp
+-------------------+-------------------+
|          prev_time|CAL_COMPLETION_TIME|
+-------------------+-------------------+
|2019-04-26 01:19:10|2019-04-26 01:19:35|
+-------------------+-------------------+
```

**Pyspark:**

```
df1.withColumn("sub", F.when(((F.col("CAL_COMPLETION_TIME").cast("long")-F.col("prev_time").cast("long"))/60 < 30), F.lit("LESSTHAN30")).otherwise(F.lit("GREATERTHAN"))).show()

+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
|          prev_time|CAL_COMPLETION_TIME|       sub|
+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
|2019-04-26 01:19:10|2019-04-26 01:19:35|LESSTHAN30|
+-------------------+-------------------+----------+
```

**Spark.sql**

```
df1.createOrReplaceTempView("df1")
spark.sql("select prev_time, CAL_COMPLETION_TIME, IF(((CAST(CAL_COMPLETION_TIME as bigint) - CAST(prev_time as bigint))/60)<30,'LESSTHAN30','GREATER') as difference_duration from df1").show()

+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|          prev_time|CAL_COMPLETION_TIME|difference_duration|
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
|2019-04-26 01:19:10|2019-04-26 01:19:35|         LESSTHAN30|
+-------------------+-------------------+-------------------+
```

Comment: Is there a way to have millisecond or microsecond resolution on those times?